# ignoring duplicate entries in t:dataList JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datalist

I'm new to JSF and I have following problem.
I have several container with persons. These persons can have questionnaire containers, that contain 3 questions.

Now I want to search for persons and display which Questions they answerded wiht yes.

My problem is, if a person has more than one questionnaire and has answered yes in every questionnaire, then it is displayed for every questionnaire.

How can I check if a question was alredy answered in a previous questionnaire?

```
 <t:dataList value="#{persons.questions}" var="qu" >
        <t:dataList value="#{qu.attribute}" var="att">
               <h:outputText value="Q1 &lt;br/&gt;" 
                             rendered="#{att.QuestId == 1 and att.attValue == true} "     
                             escape="false" /> 
               <h:outputText value="Q2 &lt;br/&gt;" 
                             rendered="#{att.QuestId == 2 and att.attValue == true} "   
                             escape="false" /> 
               <h:outputText value="Q3" 
                             rendered="#{att.QuestId == 3 and att.attValue == true} " />
        </t:dataList> 
 </t:dataList>
```

The Output could look like:

```
Person | Question 
A.A    | Q1
       | Q1
_______|_Q2_______
B.B    | Q2
       | Q3
```

But it should be:

```
Person | Question 
A.A    | Q1
_______|_Q2_______
B.B    | Q2
       | Q3
```

Comment: The result list appears to be an outcome of wrong database design or a wrong SQL query executed on the database. Please fix them, if they are causing problems instead of fiddling with alternatives. Also, you are using a `<br/>` tag in the value attribute of `<h:outputText>` (`value="Q1 &lt;br/&gt;" `) by setting its `escape` attribute to `false`. This is really not a good practice. Consider the design the other way round to exclude the need of `<br/>` itself in its entirely.

Comment: what should be wrong in detail ?
in the example Person A.A has answered 2 questionnaieres. For example the first 2 month ago and the second yesterday.
in the first he answerded Q1: yes, Q2: no Q3: no
in the second he answered Q1: yes, Q2: yes, Q3 no

Comment: Then you are supposed to display the list questionnaire-wise and person-wise. `q1` being repeated for the person `A.A` is hereby supposed to arrive from two different questionnaires. Thus, they are essentially not duplicate and seem  perfectly reasonable, if the list is shown  questionnaire-wise and person-wise (again assuming the database design is correct and the SQL statement is correctly formulated that retrieves the data that you need).

Answer (score 0):

You should filter that in e.g. your database query... This is not something that a jsd component should fix/correct.